# Retrofit crashing on api call

Tags: android, retrofit

```
ntime/thread.cc:1329] Throwing new exception 'length=365; index=1283' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=365; index=1283
```

So When I call my api its crashing, only on this particular call.All other api calls are going fine. Just this one crashing, but I see nothing wrong with it.

```
getAttendance = `App.getEvent(root.getContext()).getAttendance("value",eventid);`
```

Comment: More info could help, request, response, etc

Comment: With just that line I have no idea what the app is doing, but I can tell you that you trying to access an array of 365 positions (perhaps 1 position per anual day) with an index of 1283 which is greater than 365 so it is out of bounds.

Comment: same issue as here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1486 but this solution didnt work for me. strangely when i generated build apk it run correctly, but not when i run via studio. even if i disable instant run